# Python py2exe Problems?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, py2exe

I coded a python application with a GUI in `Tkinter` with pictures. Now that I have finished, I am trying to convert it to a `.exe` with `py2exe`. All my pictures are in the same folder as my python file and setup file, but when I try to convert my python file via the `Command Prompt`, I get error messages saying that my .`ico` file is not defined and that it can not copy it. I think the problem is due to my `setup.py` file. How do I allow my images to be copied into the new `.exe` executable file without getting errors I have never used `py2exe` before.

Setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['Gui.py'])
```

Error:

[image: error]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have just forgotten to define your icon:

```
cfg = {
    'py2exe.icon':'icon.ico',
    ...
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I put this into my code? Do I put it right after I import everything on lines 1 and 2

Comment: Sorry, I answered a bit hastily there.  I miss-interpreted your error. It seems to be an issue with tkinter, have you set your icon in tkinter?

tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, '-default', 'iconfile.ico')

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `setup.py` like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

data_files = [('', [r'standardicon.ico'])]

setup(
    windows =['Gui.py'],
    data_files = data_files
)
```